# How to get those elements which are at the same position in two 2D matrix in Python using a filter?

Tags: python, list, filter

I am trying to get the elements as a list if any of them in the same position in two 2D matrices.

Let's consider matrix A and matrix B

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
B = [[0, 2, 5],[6, 2, 4],[7, 8, 1]]
```

The resultant list should be

```
C = [2, 7, 8]
```

I have tried using a filter but it is not working.

```
def find(A):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if A[i][j] == B[i][j]:
                return A[i][j]
            else:
                return False

A = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
B = [[0, 2, 5],[6, 2, 4], [7, 8, 1]]

C = filter(find, A)

for element in C:
    print(element)
```

**Note: Please use a filter to achieve the target.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using filter:

```
def find(L):
            A, B = L
            if A == B:
                return True
            else:
                return False

A = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
B = [[0, 2, 5],[6, 2, 4], [7, 8, 1]]

# flatten lists
A = [item for row in A for item in row]
B = [item for row in B for item in row]

C = filter(find, zip(A,B))

# filter returns a tuple for each row but we only want the single element
C = [item[0] for item in C]

print(list(C))
```

Gives us

```
[2, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```py
def func(t):
    return True if t[0] == t[1] else False

A = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
B = [[0, 2, 5],[6, 2, 4],[7, 8, 1]]

C = [item1 for lst1, lst2 in zip(A, B) for item1, item2 in filter(func, zip(lst1, lst2))]
```

```py
>>> C
[2, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

***Basic Answer***

First we loop over A and B, i and z now holds the inner lists.

Then we loop over those inner lists using g and q, if they are equal, we append them to the empty list.

```
to_fill = []
for i,z in zip(A,B):
    for g,q in zip(i,z):
        if g==q:
            to_fill.append(g)
```

Adapt it as you please.

Comment: It can written in a more compact way, however, for educational purposes it is better to see it as a loop.

Comment: Actually, I want to get it using the filter function.

Comment: @user3804152 u never mentioned that in ur question. u said u tried filter but it didnt work (obviously)

Comment: Sry about that. I thought it was understandable! I am editing.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of achieving what you want is by using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray(A)
B = np.asarray(B)
C = A[A==B]
```

Comment: Thnx. But I want to achieve this using a filter.